# Identify processes related to a productivity traking software and start and stop them

Tags: windows-10, powershell

In my personal computer I have a productivity tracking software from my work, the problem is that is always running even in out of office hours, so I want to create a powershell script so I can start and stop the software in office hours.

so I think that I need to identify all the processes related to that software and then create an script to stop and start those processes.

what aproach would you recommend?

I was playing with this script, but I can get it to work also

```
@echo off
$p = Get-Process -Name "notepad.exe"
Stop-Process -InputObject $p
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.HasExited}
```

Comment: Did you even try this? What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly...

```
@echo off`
```

...is not something PowerShell will execute, since that is a batch file thing.

```
# Results
<#
 @echo off
At line:1 char:7
+ @echo off
+       ~~~
Unexpected token 'off' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ @echo off
+ ~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@echo' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$echo'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
#>
```

For the rest, you need to be in the PowerShell host for those commands to even run and you are not showing yourself starting PowerShell at all. For stopping an existing running process.

You can just do that in one line.

```
Stop-Process -Name 'notepad' -Force
```

Starting a process is just as simple.

If you are saying you have multiple running processes of the same name, then you'd have to capture the process on startup. However, what you did not do that? How are you planning to know which exactly named process you should cancel?

You'd have to look at other properties of the same-named process to find the unique one you'd need to kill off. Such as its full window title, etc.

```
$ProcessTarget = Start-Process -FilePath 'notepad.exe' -PassThru

Stop-Process $ProcessTarget.Id -Force

try   {(Get-Process $ProcessTarget.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).HasExited} 
Catch {$ProcessTarget.HasExited}
```